# How to deal with circular foreign key

Tags: database-design

I have two tables:

```
Games(
    name,
    current_step, #foreign key to Steps table
    #other fields...
)

Steps(
    name,
    game_id, #foreign key to Games table
    #other fields...
)
```

In other words what I want to achieve is a Steps table where each step is linked to its game and in some way I want to keep track of current step. Which is the best design to do this? Is circular foreign key acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put the step in the `games` table, it's unnecessary.

In your `steps` table, make a bit column like `current_step`, and add a unique filtered index on `(game_id, current_step) WHERE current_step = 1`.

This will prevent duplicates and prevent the circular reference and data integrity issues that are sure to ensue.

Comment: I did not thought about it because current step is an information I quite always need when I retrieve a game. However I think I'll use the design you suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a circular reference to model your case. I would rather use a function to check if your current step belongs to the Steps table and add check constraint to the Games table on current_step field. A mock up is as below.

```
Games Table
-----------------
Games(
    name,
    current_step,
    #other fields...
)


Step Table
----------------
Steps(
    name,
    game_id, #foreign key to Games table
    #other fields...
)


checkStep Function
---------------------
function checkStep( @game_id ... )
returns ...
as
begin
    if exists (select * from Steps where game_id = @game_id)
        return 'True'
    else
        return 'False'
end


Check Constraint
----------------------
alter table games add constraint ck_current_step
check (checkStep(current_step)) = 'True')
```

Comment: Why do we need to have the current step in the `games` table to begin with?

Comment: I guess the questioner intends to preserve the state of the game through current_step attribute. Just a guess...

Comment: Yes, having current_step inside game table would be useful because when I retrieve a game I quite always need the current step, however I think that @JNK approach is the cleanest and probably I will use it. Thank you anyway.